# get column names from csv file using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am using pandas to read a heavy csv file as below

```
import pandas
csv_file_path = "/Users/import.csv"
csv_data = pandas.read_csv(csv_file_path, names=data_mapping_field_values)
```

When i use `csv_data.columns`, i got below

```
Index([u'Domain', u'RefSubNets', u'RefIPs', u'IDN_Domain'], dtype='object')
```

But i want only a list of columns like below

```
[u'Domain', u'RefSubNets', u'RefIPs', u'IDN_Domain']
```

How can we access only columns of a csv file as a list using pandas?

Comment: You can use `tolist()`. `csv_data.columns.tolist()`

Comment: By the way, if it is not for display purposes, most of the time it is better to leave them as indices. You can still iterate, slice and do all the things that you can do with the lists but you can also use index methods.